# Curve Number equation in ArcGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, hydrology

I have a floating-point raster of Curve Numbers (70-91) and I'm attempting to use the curve number equation to create a weight raster for flow accumulation, to determine runoff for a single rainfall event. I'm familiar with this curve number equation:

[image: formula]

*where*

```
Q = total runoff
P = preciptation (1 inch in this case)
0.2S = initial abstractions
0.8 = potential maximum retention after runoff begins
```

The 2 outside the first bracket means to the power of 2. Firstly, I am unsure how to calculate the power of 2 in the Raster Calculator. Also, would precipitation be an input raster or just a value (1 for example)?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @KirkKuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189732/curve-number-equation/263443#comment286259_189732):

> To raise to the nth power, use the `pow` function, or `sqr` to square it.